# Why is Deltek off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request, close-reasons

https://superuser.com/questions/580843/is-there-any-way-for-an-individual-to-learn-deltek-vision?noredirect=1#comment710957_580843

Why was this question considered off-topic?

According to the FAQ:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

```
computer hardware,
computer software, or
personal and home computer networking
```

> and it is not about …

```
programming and software development,
video games or consoles,
websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
asking for a shopping or product recommendation,
```

> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

My question is about computer software. It seems to be exactly on topic.

Here are other questions:

[Where can I find information for learning to use Cisco IOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/33726/where-can-i-find-information-for-learning-to-use-cisco-ios)

[Learning the basics of Linux/Unix](https://superuser.com/questions/36605/learning-the-basics-of-linux-unix)

https://superuser.com/questions/172679/learning-to-debug-network-problems

All of which are still open and have answers. As far the tag question - CRM is a tag and Deltek is a CRM platform. So what reason is there to close mine, especially when I showed more research then any of the above questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out the other questions. They've been closed accordingly.

If you look at the other examples you linked to, you'll find that the most answers just consist of links to resources. This is a problem. We don't want to build up a list of links.  We want *actual answers* here. But those link-only answers are of course just the symptom of the actual issue, which is the question being too broad (e.g., how to learn using an application).

We want actual answers for questions about specific problems someone's facing. Super User is for asking about how to go about doing *XYZ* in the application, and not how to learn it from scratch. People should read the documentation, and if they encounter specific problems or need something explained, then they may ask about those here.

> My question is about computer software. It seems to be exactly on topic.

Your question is **not about the software itself**. It's about websites or organizations that may provide training for said software. This is not a specific computer problem you're facing and out of scope here, sorry.

Finally, I have to admit that even if you had a specific issue with the program in question, you problably wouldn't find a good audience here. Super User is for enthusiast computer users in a home environment, and people rarely do CRM just for the fun of it.

Comment: Understood. I am going to flag the question for migration to Project Management beta. That might be a better place for it.

Comment: Questions should not be migrated to Beta sites, and also I'm not sure your question would be a better fit there (or any Stack Exchange site, to be honest). Your best bet is to ask on their Meta if your question would be suitable there, and then reask proper.